# Pass NULL and Blank as parameter in SQL Parameter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this strange requirement to pass 'NULL' and "" values from database which should be either '=' or 'IN' Operator.

I have written the query but seems like it's not working.

```
select * from bookDetails where RBN in ("",null);
```

Thank you

Comment: IN null doesn't work. Do `where RBN = "" or RBN is null` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can't use null in **IN**.

`select * from bookDetails where RBN = '' OR RBN IS NULL`

Comment: Remove extra keyword `RBN` from where clause. Can include a reference for [Working with NULL values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html)

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is a special value, and it has to be handled separately using [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null) operator, and cant be used in the [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) operator:

```
select * from bookDetails 
where RBN = '' 
      OR RBN IS NULL
```

Comment: This way its possible but I have to pass both inside 'IN' param only.

Comment: @Akash you cannot use `IN(..)` or `=` or `<>` etc to check for `NULL` values. These are special values. Read: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html

Comment: @Akash In this case you can use `SELECT * FROM bookDetails WHERE IFNULL(RBN, '') IN ('')`

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I will not go this route, as it kills any chance of using index (if defined) on the `RBN` column.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I know but in case he have to use `IN` this is the only solution I know at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query to get expected results

Select * From bookDetails Where RBN = '' OR RBN IS NULL